# What is the use-case for Private Protected members in VB.NET 15.5?

Tags: vb.net, access-levels

VB.NET 15.5 introduced an additional access level for class members: `Private Protected`, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/private-protected) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels).

An example is given as

```
Private Protected internalValue As Integer
```

My understanding is that this should be equivalent to just `Protected`, meaning it is accessible in the same class and its children, but not outside.

So when is this useful and what is the difference to `Protected` members?

Comment: The exact same use case as private protected in C#, nicely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430491/what-is-the-use-case-for-the-c-7-2-private-protected-modifier).

Comment: Thanks Hans, I somehow didn't find that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The Private Protected modifier makes a class member accessible by derived types, **but only within its containing assembly**.*

Without the `Private`, a `Protected` member is accessible to derived classes in different assemblies too.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! As Hans has pointed out in a comment there also already exists the [same question for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430491/what-is-the-use-case-for-the-c-7-2-private-protected-modifier)