# Why did Microsoft coin it 'private protected' and not 'internal protected'

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

There is already a 'protected internal' which is why i'm guessing they couldn't coin 'private protected' for what it really is which is 'internal protected'. Or am I not understanding what private protected actually means?

If private protected means "Protected" but only within the assembly, then it seems counter-intuitive to call it 'private protected'.

The existing 'protected internal' modifier meaning also seems strange. For what reason would you want it to be protected **or** internal?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430491/what-is-the-use-case-for-the-c-7-2-private-protected-modifier

Comment: @DanCsharpster Yes, it has. Sorry about that. Thanks! :)